# HP LaserJet Enterprise scanning

Tags: drivers, scanner, hp-laserjet

I am using the `HP LaserJet Enterprise 500 MFP M575f` model of Scanner/Printer/Copier/Fax.

If I install it's drivers and let the setup add the printer to my devices in Windows, I do not have access to its scanning capabilities. The device is not listed in Scanner applications and also does not have Scanner-like options available.

The device obviously has a scanner built into it. I can use it from the device directly by choosing to copy something or by letting it save the scanned `.jpg` file into a network location.

How can I use the scanner of this device from my Windows PC?

A thing to note: I am using Microsoft Windows 10 (x64), but I installed Windows 8.1 (x64) drivers, since they were the latest thing available.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You actually answered it with that, it's possible the model does not support that. Write an answer and you will get accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most network-attached MFPs don't support scanner control from the PC, so ensure your model has that capability.

Looking over the specs for this specific model, it says has "Save-to-Network Folder" which means you walk up to the scanner and pick a destination folder on the network (once it's setup in the MFP) to scan to, but all scanning actions are done at the printer itself.

Any of the MFPs I've seen in the past that support scanning from a client PC always had very proprietary software for doing so, and you would want to ensure you are using drivers/utilities specific to your *exact* OS version.  In most cases though it was flakey at best, and pretty much pointless, as you still had to walk up to the scanner to put paper in (etc.) anyway.